# VoIP: Timestamp Change in RTP Header

Tags: timestamp, voip, rtp

According to the RTP RFC (3550) Timestamp must increase in each RTP packets:
"The timestamp reflects the sampling instant of the first octet in the RTP data packet.  The sampling instant MUST be derived from a clock that increments monotonically and linearly in time to allow synchronization and jitter calculations ".

We are facing issues when the Timestamp  suddenly decreases (goes back to zero) in the middle of the call, without any telephony events (such as hold/transfer). the SSRC stays the same and Sequence number increments as expected. Only the Timestamp is acting up without clear explanation.

This behaviors is causing recording loss (these RTP packets are discarded by the Recorder that captures the RTP stream).

I would like to find out if decreasing the Timestamp means lack of adherence to the RTP RFC and also what would be the possible cause for such behavior ?

This issue happens on Cisco 7942 phones with firmware Version: SCCP42.9-4-2SR3-1S.

On Cisco 8841 phones (and exact same environment) the issue is a bit different: when the timestamp resets the sequence number also resets, in the same time (packet), which does not lead to recording loss.

Thanks

Kobster

Comment: That seems very strange that the sequence number resets on Cisco 8841 phones. The sequence number is supposed to only go to zero upon rollover during the same session.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp used in RTP to determine order of packets received

In some network condition packet 3 can be delivered before packet 1,2 etc.

So if you have jitterbuffer you should reorder packets acordinly to timestamp.

If timestamp out of jitter buffer length - just skip incorrect packets.

So continuois decrease of timestamp mean some bugs. You should change firmware or contact cisco.

Comment: "Sequence number increments as expected"

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC-3550 Section #5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.1) timestamps must be increasing:

> The timestamp reflects the sampling instant of the first octet in
> the RTP data packet.  The sampling instant MUST be derived from a
> clock that increments monotonically and linearly in time to allow
> synchronization and jitter calculations

Also you could check synchronization info from [Sender Report RTCP Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-6.4.1): NTP time and corresponding timestamp, perhaps Cisco phones notify about such behavior

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !
I think this phenomenon stems from live “bouncing” of the call across different media servers (similar to S4B’s adaptability capability), due to latency/BW issues (or CPU/RAM overload on the media server) and it happens regardless of telephony events such as hold, transfer or conference. This issue happens only to the customer’s side so maybe this side is live-migrated to a more adjacent media server.
Once again thank you for your support and confirmation that this is indeed not complying with the RTP RFC.